# Error in executing Java program appium and other exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium

I am trying to execute following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  driver=Capabilities();
        
      //xPath id className, androidUIautomator  //tagname[@attribute='value']

//Registration of the device
//driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='iMSSO_Alert1_Continue_button']").click();

//driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='btnAgree']").click();


driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='USER']").sendKeys("aris");
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='PASSWORD']").sendKeys("kKL2WBU7ggCeMh4izUY4Kg==");
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='btnLogin']").click(); 

}}




package appiumsample1;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
 
public class base1 {

public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {


DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My tab");
caps.setCapability("udid", "ce12182cabcaaa27017e"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone/name of the device
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity");
caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");


AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
return driver;



/*public static void main(String[] args) {

//Set the Desired Capabilities
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
caps.setCapability("udid", "ce12182cabcaaa27017e"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone/name of the device
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity");
caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");





//Instantiate Appium Driver
try {
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} */


// UI Automator tool 

}
```

Exception

> remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: Cannot start the
>   'com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit' application. Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\SINGTO2\AppData\Local\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s ce12182cabcaaa27017e shell am start -W -n com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit/com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity
>   -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>       System info: host: 'TFL0074ALKVTMLM', ip: '10.69.131.113', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>       remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start
>   the 'com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit' application. Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\SINGTO2\AppData\Local\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s ce12182cabcaaa27017e shell am start -W -n com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit/com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity
>   -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
>           at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>           at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>       System info: host: 'TFL0074ALKVTMLM', ip: '10.69.131.113', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:323)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:86)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:96)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:94)
>       at appiumsample1.base1.Capabilities(base1.java:25)
>       at appiumsample1.base2.main(base2.java:13)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
>       ... 15 more
>       Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: Cannot start the 'com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit' application.
>   Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\SINGTO2\AppData\Local\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s ce12182cabcaaa27017e shell am start -W -n com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit/com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity
>   -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>       System info: host: 'TFL0074ALKVTMLM', ip: '10.69.131.113', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>       remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start
>   the 'com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit' application. Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\SINGTO2\AppData\Local\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s ce12182cabcaaa27017e shell am start -W -n com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit/com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity
>   -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
>           at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>           at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>       at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)

Added code as per answer

```
public class base1 {

public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
        public WebDriverWait wait;
        public Dimension size;
        public String destDir;
public DateFormat dateFormat;

public (swipe) {
};


public (takeScreenShot) {
};

@BeforeMethod

public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {

DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My tab");
caps.setCapability("udid", "ce12182cabcaaa27017e"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone/name of the device
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity");
caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

}

@Test
     public void test () throws Exception {

    //Test commands
    }

@AfterMethod

    public void teardown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

/*public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {


DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My tab");
caps.setCapability("udid", "ce12182cabcaaa27017e"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone/name of the device
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity");
caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");


AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
return driver;

wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);*/




}
```

Comment: Where do you specify the target URL?

Comment: @dha edited code

Answer (score 0):

1- First check if the appium is running or not.

2- If yes, you should know that sometimes Node.js could not talk to **127.0.0.1:4723**, So use **0.0.0.0:4723** instead. Remember to change this in both code (DesiredCapabilities) and appium setting.

3- You should keep the structure of code like the following. Also using this 3 notations is required: (@BeforeMethod , @Test, @AfterMethod)

Something like this:

```
 import <...>
    .
    .

    public class sample {  //this is the main class. You shouldn't define it as static or void so you must not have main methode
    //define variables you will be use during the test        
public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
        public WebDriverWait wait;
        public Dimension size;
        public String destDir;
        public DateFormat dateFormat;
        .
        .
        .
    //define the methodes you will be use during the test 
    public (swipe) {
    ... };
    public (takeScreenShot) {
    ...};

@BeforeMethod

    public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S7 API 26");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "ce0217124184c72505"); //DeviceId from "adb devices" command
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "app_packageName"); // Your app packageName
        caps.setCapability("appActivity","app_first_activity"); // The first activity of app. You can use "Apk Info2" application to find this
        caps.setCapability("noReset","false");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
}

@Test
     public void test () throws Exception {

    //Test commands
    }

@AfterMethod

    public void teardown(){
        driver.quit();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Refers the log error say: `Original error: Cannot start the 'com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit' application.`. I think this happens because the `apps` capability misleading.

```
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity");
```

Maybe this is the true capability:

```
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", ".webview.WebActivity");
```

To make sure, [here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/) how to know `appPackage` and `appActivity`.